# Dealing with C++ "initialized but not referenced" warning for destruction of scope helpers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, warnings

In Visual Studio, I often use objects only for RAII purposes.  For example:

```
ScopeGuard close_guard = MakeGuard( &close_file, file );
```

The whole purpose of *close_guard* is to make sure that the file will be close on function exit, it is not used anywhere else.  However, Visual Studio gives me a warning that a "*local variable is initialized but not referenced*".  I want to turn this warning off for this specific case.

How do you deal with this kind of situation?  Visual Studio thinks that this object is useless, but this is wrong since it has a non-trivial destructor.

I wouldn't want to use a *#pragma warning* directive for this since it would turn off this warning even for legitimate reasons.

Comment: Could you post the code for ScopeGuard and MakeGuard (or some cut-down versions that still exhibit the behavior)?

Comment: Please read http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403758 for a possible implementation.

Comment: Which version of MSVC are you seeing this behavior in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method 1:** Use the `#pragma warning` directive.

`#pragma warning` allows selective modification of the behavior of compiler warning messages.

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4705 ) // replace 4705 with warning number

ScopeGuard close_guard = MakeGuard( &close_file, file );

#pragma warning( pop )
```

This code saves the current warning state, then it disables the warning for a specific warning code and then restores the last saved warning state.

**Method 2:** Use a workaround like the following. Visual Studio will be happy and so will you. This workaround is used in many Microsoft samples and also in other projects.

```
ScopeGuard close_guard = MakeGuard( &close_file, file );
close_guard;
```

Or you can create a `#define` to workaround the warning.

```
#define UNUSED_VAR(VAR) VAR
...
ScopeGuard close_guard = MakeGuard( &close_file, file );
UNUSED_VAR(close_guard);
```

---

Some users stated that the code presented will not work because ScopeGuard is a typedef. This assumption is wrong.

http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403758

> According to the C++ Standard, a
>   reference initialized with a temporary
>   value makes that temporary value live
>   for the lifetime of the reference
>   itself.

Comment: This was posted in [Dobb's journal](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403758) by Andrei Alexandrescu and Petru Marginean. These are two C++ players with strong background. And also I have never hard of such behavior. Will check it and comment afterwards.

Comment: ScopeGuard is in fact a typedef for a reference type, but this is not wrong. Excerpt from smink's link: "According to the C++ Standard, a reference initialized with a temporary value makes that temporary value live for the lifetime of the reference itself."

Comment: Yes that is the important piece in the article that makes the mechanism work. The fact that ScopeGuard is a typedef does not make the code wrong and it still works. Even if that was so we would be debating another complete different topic and not the question.

Comment: He is not misusing the interface. The ON_BLOCK_EXIT is merely a way to define a temporary variable with a generated name. The macro expands to [this code](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?referrerid=177422&t=433262). But you can continue to safely use the former code he posted.

Comment: Takes courage to say that. +1 for you and some deserved admiration points.

Answer (score 9):

If your object has a non-trivial destructor, Visual Studio should *not* be giving you that warning.  The following code does not generate any warnings in VS2005 with warnings turned all the way up (/W4):

```
class Test
{
public:
    ~Test(void) { printf("destructor\n"); }
};

Test foo(void) { return Test(); }

int main(void)
{
    Test t = foo();
    printf("moo\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Commenting out the destructor gives a warning; the code as-is does not.

Comment: The problem seems to be that 'ScopeGuard' is actually a reference typedef to an object with a non-trivial destructor.  VS doesn't seem to be 'smart enough' to deal with this correctly.

Answer (score 3):

We use:

```
static_cast<void>(close_guard);
```

for variables that the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: I'd say that casting to void is possibly one situation where a C-style cast is justified in C++ over a static_cast...

Answer (score 3):

In some of VC++ header files, MS defines a macro:

```
#define UNUSED(x) x
```

used like:

```
ScopeGuard close_guard = MakeGuard( &close_file, file );
UNUSED(close_guard);
```

Which silences the warning, and documents it.

Comment: UNUSED_ALWAYS is also defined in most windows programs, and works the same way.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use macro all the way in this case:

```
#define SCOPE_GUARD(guard, fn, param) \
    ScopeGuard guard = MakeGuard(fn, param); \
    static_cast<void>(guard)
```

now your code is nice and short:

```
SCOPE_GUARD(g1, &file_close, file1);
SCOPE_GUARD(g2, &file_close, file2);
```

One advantage of this approach is that later on you can add `__LINE__`, `__func__` etc to log the guard actions later if needed.

Answer (score 2):

*Well, in this case ScopeGuard is actually a typedef to a reference type. This wouldn't work unfortunately.*

Wouldn't that mean the whole ScopeGuard doesn't work, because in that case the destructor won't be called???

Comment: In case someone is wondering where is came from. It was a comment by the OP on an answer by 'Sherm Pendley' that got deleted. I assume Sherm deleted it since the comment suggested his solution wouldn't be usable.

Comment: No, I meant that declaring the variable before using it wouldn't work since it's actually a reference.

Comment: Actually, that's fine... binding a reference to a temporary extends that temporarys' lifetime to that of the reference.  Example:
{ string& s = string("hello ") + "world!";  cout << s; }  this code is fine, because the temporary returned by operator+ lives until the next closing brace.

Answer (score 1):

You can scope the #pragma warning around that line of code only by using

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:XXXX)
your code here;
#pragma warning(pop)
```

or

```
#pragma warning(disable:XXXX)
your code here;
#pragma warning(default:XXXX)
```

You can also use `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(close_guard);` after the line of code above.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in practice, I would grudingly go with the #pragma disable... or 'UNUSED'. However, as a main rule, code should be kept clean of warnings even at the cost of some extra bulk.  It should compile in multiple different compilers on different platforms and operating systems without warnings.  If it does not, the code has be to fixed so that it does. Maintaining code that generates warnings at gcc -Wall level is not a good idea.

Compiler warnings are your friend, and should be heeded as a matter or principle. Even when it means things have to be implemented in a bit bulkier and more verbose ways. Pays for itself in the long run as the code is ported, maintained, and lives on forever...

Comment: This compiler warning is pedantic.  disable it outright.  It hurts self documenting code in cases, ex:  void foo(int /*numberOfWidgets*/);

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'volatile' to the ScopeGuard declaration.

Comment: Nothing really in this case, except maybe silence the compiler warning.

Comment: Volatile tells the compiler that the variable can be changed outside of its knowledge.  I use it a lot for hardware registers.  If the variable is volatile, the compiler has to create it and assign it.

Comment: Um... the volatile declaration also tells the compiler that the object can be modified outside of normal code flow, i.e., don't cache anything at any time ever.

MSN

Answer (score 0):

I use smink's post above and have only to add that I stick a comment next to the #define saying // used to suppress warning [warning number] in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly create the ScopeGuardImpl1 object, provided that there aren't so many parameters in the cases you're using that the result is unreadable. That way you'd avoid the reference-initialized-with-temporary that the VS warning apparently fails to understand. The cost is having to spell things out longhand, rather than getting the MakeGuard template magic.

Answer (score -3):

The core issue here seems to really be that the compiler does not quite understand what you are going at... which seems to be to use scoping semantics in C++ to get some code called when a variable is deallocated even when it is not being used. Right?  That mechanism itself strikes me as borderline... a compiler should have the right to remove unused variables but the C++ construction semantics really messes these things up.  No other way to do this that is less sleight-of-hand?

Comment: RAII is a powerful technique.  You should really consider reading http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403758

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty interesting.  But in there, they do seem to access the created object in the ".dismiss()" call that would seem to make it used?  So would the VC compiler complain then?

Comment: It wouldn't complain if you use the ".dismiss()" function, of course.  But this is not the case here ;)